# How do I extract links with a specific domain name using PHP and Regex?

Tags: php, html, regex, url

I am trying to extract urls that contain `www.domain.com` from a database column that contains HTML. The regex has to filter out `www2.domain.com` instances and external urls like `www.domainxyz.com`. It should only search for properly coded anchor links.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
    $content = '<html>
    <title>Random Website</title>
    <body>
        Click <a href="http://domainxyz.com">here</a> for foobar
        Another site is http://www.domain.com
        <a href="http://www.domain.com/test">Test 1</a>
        <a href="http://www2.domain.com/test">Test 2</a>
        <Strong>NOT A LINK</strong>
    </body>
    </html>';

    $regex = "((https?)\:\/\/)?";
    $regex .= "([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,4})"; 
    $regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?";
    $regex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?";
    $regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; 
    $regex .= "([www\.domain\.com])";

    $matches = array(); //create array
    $pattern = "/$regex/";

    preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches); 

    print_r(array_values(array_unique($matches[0])));
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo implode("<br>", array_values(array_unique($matches[0])));
?>
```

I am looking for this to find and output only http://www.domain.com/test.

How can I modify my Regex to accomplish this?

Comment: What about a DOMDocument and DOMXPath based solution? I see you just extract the href attribute values, right?

Comment: Thanks, I considered this but would such a solution be possible if grabbing the html from a database query?

Comment: Please check [this code](http://ideone.com/L1DDDp). I'd suggest using regex here only as a means of last resort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a much safer way to extract the `a` `href` attribute values containing `www.domain.com` where the key is the XPath `'//a[contains(@href, "www.domain.com")]'`:

```
$html = "YOUR_HTML_STRING"; // Your HTML string
$dom = new DOMDocument;    
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$arr = array();
$links = $xpath->query('//a[contains(@href, "www.domain.com")]');

foreach($links as $link) { 
   array_push($arr, $link->getAttribute("href"));
}

print_r($arr);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/L1DDDp), result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.domain.com/test
)
```

As you see, you can use the DOMDocument and DOMXPath with a string, too.

The code is self-explanatory, the XPath expression just means *find all `<a>` tags that have a `href` attribute containing `www.domain.com`*.

Comment: Thank you for sharing a how to on the DOMDocument and DOMXPath approach. Since this is a better solution than regex, I ended up going this route :)